# How to Perform self join to a table in such a way that few variables are grouped on different condition

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have to generate a report that gives simple count of customers per source. But because a few of the sources have to be grouped based on a different date condition, I am running the same query twice. I there a way I can self join in a such a way that I can get the report in one query.

The table JCS is as below:
JCS Table Structure

```
Card_no  Source, Branch,     Bill_date  etc     etc     etc
1A1       ABC      AA     '2019-09-01'
1A2       ABC      AA     '2019-09-01' 
1A3       PQR      CC     '2019-09-01'
1A4       STO      CC     '2019-09-01'
1A5       STO      DD     '2019-09-02'
2A1       PQR      BB     '2019-09-01'
2A2       PDR      BB     '2019-09-03'
2A3       PDR      DD     '2019-09-01'
2A4       ABC      CC     '2019-09-01'
```

There are many columns and thousands of rows but above 4 are columns of interest. The first column Card_no is unique, Source tells us from where the customers have come from, Branch is which outlet they have visited and Bill_date is the billing date.
Any Source can go to any Branch. Therefore, each source will have an try for all the available branches.

What was required is simple:

```
select Source, count(*) from JCS.
```

But what IS required is that certain branches' count needs to be taken after Sept 1st. Therefore, two queries I am using are:

```
select Source, count(*) from JCS
where Branch not in ('AA','CC')
```

Result:

```
Source  Count
ABC      40 
PQR      36
STO      19
..       ..
```

And:

```
select Source, count(*) from JCS
where Branch in ('AA','CC') and day(Bill_date) > 1
```

Result:

```
Source  Count
STO      42 
PQR      36
..       ..
..       ..
```

Can I write a join in such a way that I can get the required output using a single query.

```
Select a.source, count(a.source) + count(b.source) [Total_Customers]
from JCS a LEFT JOIN JCS b on a.source = b.source 
and a.card_no != b.card_no
where a.Branch not in ('AA','CC') and b.Branch in ('AA','CC') and 
day(b.Bill_date) > 1
group by a.source
```

I know there will be lots of duplication in my above query, is there any other way I can accomplish the task or do I need to stick to using two queries as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give your required output.

```
SELECT Source, COUNT(CASE WHEN Branch NOT IN ('AA','CC') THEN 1 
  WHEN Branch in ('AA','CC') and day(Bill_date) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)  
FROM JCS
GROUP BY Source
```